# How to fix 'Message reply took too long' in WatchKit

Tags: objective-c

i have write 'sendMessage' To my iphone,but cannot receive any thing, in my iphone , I have writed 'WCSession Delegate' like didReceiveMessage:replyHandler',help Me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32283077/8294374

Comment: still not working